# Python method decorator that modifies the class

Tags: python, decorator

Essentially, I need to keep track of the methods that I wrap with this decorator to use later by editing the original object. The code works if I call the method, but if I don't, the code in the wrapper never executes. The wrapper is the only place where I receive the object where I can modify it. So, I need some other way to modify the object without calling a method that I'm decorating in it.

I've been trying so many different ways but I just can't get this to work.

```
import functools

def decorator3(**kwargs):
    print(1)
    def decorator(function):
        print(2)
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(self, *args):
            print(3)
            self.__test__ = "test worked"
            function(self, *args)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = "test"

  @decorator3()
  def test(self):
    print(self.a)

t = Test()
#t.test()
print(t.__test__)
```

Comment: If you want a decorator to modify a class instance, without having to call any particular method on that instance, you'd have to apply the decorator to `__init__()`.

Comment: Fundamentally, it just doesn't sound like a decorator is the correct tool here, which is to *modify callables*. As noted above, you *could* decorate `__init__` which would mean that (in most cases) the wrapper would be called, but that seems like a you are shoehorning the use of a decorator as a solution where it doesn't fit

Comment: I need to keep track of the methods that I decorate later on in the code. Basically, I decorate it to "flag" the method, and I have multiple classes with different methods that I need to flag. I will be calling decorator3 in other classes, so I don't see how putting the decorator in ``__init__`` will help. By editing the original class, I can later on put the method in a dictionary which I was hoping the decorator would do.

Comment: @Kremla again, **fundamentally** decorating is not going to be able to modify an instance when you use the decorator. At that point, the instance doesn't likely *even exist*. Decorators work *when they are called* (i.e. when you use the `@deco`) syntax. The wrapper is called when the decorated method is called. This is how this tool works.  I'm not sure what you are looking for. If you gave more details, someone might be able to suggest an alternative approach/design.

Comment: This is an xy problem. You have 'solved' your original problem by deciding a decorator is the best answer and are now having trouble getting it to do what you want. Everyone here is telling you that a decorator is not supposed to do this and maybe that's not what your looking for to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Methods live on classes, not instances. If you want to keep track of decorated methods, then having access to the class is fine. You do not have to wait until there is an instance. Can you please clarify what you *want to achieve*, not what you *want to do*?

Answer (score 0):

Your code parts execute in different times.

The outer decorator function, where you print "1", is called where you read `@decorator3()`. The result of calling this function, `decorator`, is then immediately applied to the decorated function (resp. method), where you read the "2".

In your case, the inner decorator replaces the method with a different function which calls the original method. Only if you call this, you reach "3".

So:

- at 1, you don't know anything about your function.
- at 2, you know your function, but not in which class it lives in.
- at 3, you know your object, but only if your function is called.

You have to decide what exactly you want to do: according to your description, you want to flag the functions. That's what you perfectly can do in "2".

You say

> I need to keep track of the methods that I decorate later on in the code. Basically, I decorate it to "flag" the method, and I have multiple classes with different methods that I need to flag. I will be calling decorator3 in other classes, so I don't see how putting the decorator in **init** will help. By editing the original class, I can later on put the method in a dictionary which I was hoping the decorator would do.

Maybe the following works:

```
import functools

def method_flagger(function):
    function._flag = "flag"
    return function

list_of_methods = []

def flag_reader(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        for i in dir(self.__class__):
        #for i, j in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
            method_wrapper = getattr(self, i)
            if hasattr(getattr(self, i), "_flag"):
                list_of_methods.append((self, i))
        return function(self, *args)
    return wrapper

class Test:
    @flag_reader
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "test"

    @method_flagger
    def test(self):
        print(self.a)

    @method_flagger
    def test2(self):
        print(self.a)

t1 = Test()
t2 = Test()
#t.test()
#print(t.__test__)

print(list_of_methods)
```

It gives me the output

```
[(<__main__.Test object at 0x000001D56A435860>, 'test'), (<__main__.Test object at 0x000001D56A435860>, 'test2'), (<__main__.Test object at 0x000001D56A435940>, 'test'), (<__main__.Test object at 0x000001D56A435940>, 'test2')]
```

so for each affected object instance and each decorated function, we get a tuple denoting these both.